# Anonymize html with regex

Tags: html, regex, anonymize

I'm trying to anonymize a HTML string with regex, for an SQL query.

https://regex101.com/r/QWt1E1/1

```
(?<!\<)[^<>\s](?!\>)
```

```
<p><em>Hi [User</em></p>
<p><em>Tack f&ouml;r visat intresse.</em></p>
<p><em>Good luck!</em><em>&nbsp;</em></p>
<p><em>Sincerely</em></p>
```

```
<p><em>nn nnnnn</nm></p>
<p><em>nnnn nnnnnnnn nnnnn nnnnnnnnn</nm></p>
<p><em>nnnn nnnnn</nm><em>nnnnnn</nm></p>
<p><em>nnnnnnnnn</nm></p>
```

The plan was to replace every character that is not within <>, with an `n`.
It almost works, but in my example it replaces the `e` in `</em>`. Not sure why and how to fix that.

How can I adjust the regex to not replace the `e` in the example?

Comment: What language are you implementing this in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative lookahead for `[^<>]*>` instead of just `>`, to ensure that the current position is not followed by a `>` before any other angle brackets (because that would indicate you're currently inside a tag).

This also means that you can drop the lookbehind:

```
[^<>\s](?![^<>]*>)
          ^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/QWt1E1/3

Still, it would be better to parse the HTML using an HTML parser, if at all possible

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Needed it to be regex, to run it in an SQL query against a postgresql database.